# Preference pane - Add action on button

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspreferencepane

I am a Windows Programmer and I create a first my program for Mac OS X.
In XCode with wizard I create a preference pane and add button, but I dont know how I can add action for this button. This action must run external program.

How I can add this action?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Write a method as `IBAction` then [assign the action through drag and drop](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQtwIwAw&url=http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/&ei=0HnhUsOYIaqA2QXD0oDYBQ&usg=AFQjCNEp9Su30Y6Cj9ME6m8Oet75lPXvDg&sig2=wtF2NcY0EmVvYABr8AUcnQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.b2I).

```
- (IBAction)checkboxClicked:(id)sender
```

Comment: I can not create this action in section Automation -> NSPreferencePane. This File is Locked for editing